# How to treat hex string as raw data in R

Tags: r

I have stored some data in SQL Server as blob. If i make a direct query against the database, the blob columns are returned as raw data(hexadecimal) which i can then use to write the blob as files on the end system.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "SQL Server", Server = "localhost\\sql2019", 
    Database = "DocumentData", Trusted_Connection = "True")

blobs <- dbGetQuery(con,"select * from Blob")

str(blobs$spectra[2][[1]]) #this returns raw [1:1678544] ff d8 ff e0 ...
```

But if i execute the same query through a webservice, the hexadecimal data is returned as a string. The hexadecimal digits are the same in both cases. Here is the sample code:

```
data<-jsonlite::fromJSON("https://localhost:5001/Spectra")
str(data$spectraBLOB) #this returns chr "FFD8FFE0"| __truncated__
```

So my question is how do i convert a character array (of hexadecimal digits) to raw vector so that i can use the hexadecimal raw data to recreate the file on end system. Sample code that saves the raw data vector to a file on end system is:

```
rawToJpeg <- function(pic_data) {
  f = file(paste0('c:/temp/blob_file.jpg'), "wb")
  writeBin(object = pic_data, con = f)
  close(f)
}

rawToJpeg(blobs$spectra[2][[1]])#works with raw data
rawToJpeg(data$spectraBLOB)     #does not work as expected with string of hexadecimal
```

Any ideas how do i go about solving it (or changing the type of hexadecimal string to hexadecimal raw)?

Answer (score -1):

Code to parse hexadecimal string as a vector for raws:

```
sst <- strsplit(data$spectraBLOB, "")[[1]]
hex_string_vector <- paste0(sst[c(TRUE, FALSE)], sst[c(FALSE, TRUE)])
raw_hex_vector = as.raw(as.hexmode(hex_string_vector))
```